# Verifying digital signature created by pycryptodome in WEB Crypto API

Tags: javascript, python, cryptography, digital-signature, pycryptodome

I am signing SHA512 hash with RSA and save it to file. The hash is the same on both python and javascript, but signature can not be verified. Python code:

```
from Cryptodome.Hash import SHA512
from Cryptodome.PublicKey import RSA
from Cryptodome.Signature import pkcs1_15

hash = SHA512.new(someByteArray)
#This is equal to digest generated in JavaScript
hashDigest = hashPDF.hexdigest()
pk = RSA.importKey(privateKey)
signature=pkcs1_15.new(pk).sign(hashPDF)
#Write signature to file
with open("storage/{0}.sig".format(hashDigest), 'wb+') as f:
        f.write(signature)

#Then JavaScript request occurs return content of saved signature in base64

from base64 import b64encode
from flask import jsonify
with open("storage/{0}.sig".format(pdfHashDigest), "rb") as f:
        sign = b64encode(f.read())
return jsonify({"sign":sign.decode("utf-8")})
```

JavaScript:

```
var hash=await crypto.subtle.digest('SHA-512', Uint8Array.from(atob(someBase64content), c => c.charCodeAt(0)))
//This is equal to python hashDigest
var hashDigest = hashArray.map(b => b.toString(16).padStart(2, '0')).join('');
var cryptoKey=await crypto.subtle.importKey('spki', this.pemToArrayBuffer(publicKey), {name: 'RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5', hash: 'SHA-512'}, false, ["verify"])
//Always false
var result=await crypto.subtle.verify("RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5", cryptoKey, Uint8Array.from(atob(signature), c => c.charCodeAt(0)), hash)
```

I tried different ways to convert base64 signature into ArrayBuffer to use in Web Crypto API: rfc4648.js, new TextEncoder(), custom conversions to Uint8Array, but result is always false. Also i tried to verify signature using forge (https://github.com/digitalbazaar/forge) but result is also false.

Where am i getting wrong? I tried to compare byte values of hash, which goes to input of signing functions, but actually it is Crypto.Hash object on python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`sign`/`verify`](https://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/signature/pkcs1_v1_5.html#pkcs-1-v1-5-rsa) implementation in the Python-code doesn't perform hashing automatically, i.e. the user must *explicitly* hash the data before signing. During verification, the user must therefore verify the signature against the hash of the data.

The [`sign`](https://gist.github.com/pedrouid/b4056fd1f754918ddae86b32cf7d803e#rsassa-pkcs1-v1_5---sign)/[`verify`](https://gist.github.com/pedrouid/b4056fd1f754918ddae86b32cf7d803e#rsassa-pkcs1-v1_5---verify) implementation in the JavaScript-code performs hashing automatically, i.e. the user must not hash the data before signing. During verification, the user must therefore verify the signature against the data (and *not* against the hash of the data). The hash algorithm is specified in the key i.e. in [`generateKey`](https://gist.github.com/pedrouid/b4056fd1f754918ddae86b32cf7d803e#rsassa-pkcs1-v1_5---generatekey)/[`importKey`](https://gist.github.com/pedrouid/b4056fd1f754918ddae86b32cf7d803e#rsassa-pkcs1-v1_5---importkey) using {hash: 'hash-algorithm'}.

The error in the posted JavaScript-code is caused by verifying the signature against the hash of the data. This is wrong. The signature must be checked against the data, i.e. in the JavaScript-code the following lines:

```
var hash=await crypto.subtle.digest('SHA-512', Uint8Array.from(atob(someBase64content), c => c.charCodeAt(0)))
...
var result=await crypto.subtle.verify("RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5", cryptoKey, Uint8Array.from(atob(signature), c => c.charCodeAt(0)), hash)
```

must be replaced by

```
var data=Uint8Array.from(atob(someBase64content), c => c.charCodeAt(0));
...
var result=await crypto.subtle.verify("RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5", cryptoKey, Uint8Array.from(atob(signature), c => c.charCodeAt(0)), data)
```

Try to perform the verification with this change.

Comment: That's right. Spended 2 nights on it. Very strage why it is not mentioned anywhere in documentation such as https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubtleCrypto/verify